# Is it possible to overwrite a PDF-header with itext?

Tags: java, pdf, itext

I merged some documents to a single pdf file.  Some of the pages have a header and footer but not all of them.  I tried to take off the headers from the documents but I can’t edit the documents. I can only play with the pdf file. 
Any suggestion?

Comment: In addition to the questions asked by Bruno (the answers to which may result in a way to actually remove existing headers and footers) please also state whether there is some simple rule concerning the header/footer positions, e.g. *all headers are in the top 10% / 2 cm / ... of their respective page but no page content is there.* If there is, you may consider hiding them by adding appropriate crop boxes or clip paths to the pages. Let it be understood, though, this would be only hiding, the information how the headers/footers are drawn, would remain in the file.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it's possible to draw a content at desired location during the merge process.

```
                //in merge a loop
                for (int i = 1; i <= pages; i++) 
                { 
                    PdfImportedPage page = copy.GetImportedPage(reader, i); 
                    PdfCopy.PageStamp stamp = copy.CreatePageStamp(page); 
                    PdfContentByte cb = stamp.GetUnderContent(); 
                    // use cb to draw your new content
                    stamp.AlterContents(); 
                    copy.AddPage(page); 
                }
```

Comment: thanks for the reply. what is copy?!

Comment: Based on your question: `I merged ...`. So, `copy` it the `PdfCopy` object which is a common way to merge pdf documents with iText: http://api.itextpdf.com/itext/com/itextpdf/text/pdf/PdfCopy.html

Comment: If i understand @user2032522 correctly, his main objective is to remove his existing headers, not creating new ones. Unfortunately he had not yet been able to define how those headers can be recognized. Your code, though, more targets the creation of new contents.

Comment: @mkl, I'm following your comments at this site. you love to play with words and offering no positive or useful solution most of the times. it seems its your job to disappoint everyone here. my solution hides that header very well. it's not just playing with words.

Comment: @VahidN Hello Vahid, while your solution may work in some cases, it may not be helpful in the context of the question posted by user2032522 I will upvote your answer, because it's a correct example, but I will cast a vote to close the question because it's not a real question: it's not specific enough!

Comment: @VahidN if you really feel like that, i wonder why you follow them then. You seem to consider taking questions seriously a bad thing, and asking for clarification in comments playing with words.

Answer (score 1):

I assume the documents you're merging don't have a predictable format. I mean: you don't know in advance if the PDFs are tagged, you don't know in advance if the headers/footers are part of an OCG, you don't know in advance if extra page boundaries are defined, you don't know in advance if the headers/footers are stored in separate XObjects, etc...

Most probably, the PDFs you're trying to merge are traditional PDFs with a traditional content stream. In this case, the definition of the headers/footers can be anywhere in the page content stream and the PDF doesn't have any notion of their existence. As far as the PDF document is concerned, the header is a string of words, paths and shapes that are drawn on the page, just like any other part of the content. For instance: there's no way the PDF can tell the difference between a header or the title of a chapter.

So please clarify: are the headers/footers defined as artifacts? are they tagged in any way? etc... If not, you should understand that your requirement is impossible to meet with any library, including iText.

Comment: thanks for the reply. I'm not merging pdf files. i'm getting files from database and merging them to one pdf file. The files have different format. some of them are pics and some simple page with some info. these pages have headers and footer that i want to overwrite

Comment: Your comment is very confusing: you're not merging PDF files, but you're getting files from database. Which files would that be? Images? TIFFs? In that case: how on earth are you going to retrieve the position of the header? As you didn't specify, I'll vote to close the question.